# What's the best method to solve a Python optimization problem with large numbers in a dataset of 3k records?

Tags: python-3.x, function, optimization, memory

Let me preface this by saying I’m a total Python novice and am trying to learn. Anyway, I have a dataset of 3k records that has 6 columns: a grouping column, 4 value columns and a group sum column for each group. The values and results are all in millions and each group can have up to 100 records. The goal is to write a function that identifies the set of values, one per record from one of the four columns that when summed equal the result column for the group and identifies the source column.

Ex

```
Group, val1, val2, val3, val4, groupsum
01, 1000000,2000000,3000000,4000000 25000000
01, 5000000,7000000,10000000,23000000
25000000
```

Result

```
01, 2000000, val2
01, 23000000, val4
```

Any ideas how to accomplish this in Python?

I’ve tried a couple functions using `itertools` but I think they were choking due to memory issues with groups over 15.